# Remove Drupal Commerce Empty Products

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I am getting empty products in my views recently after the first few rounds of having a crawler import the data for the products. Unfortunately, after deleting all but two products that existed beforehand, These "empty" products still exist. I also made sure there were no extra variation types, and cleared the commerce_line_item table. Does anybody know where I can find and get rid of these nameless products?

Here is a photo for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cLWS.png [1]

I noticed this title (this product was created by the) was able to be selected and edited.  This is the only title that shows up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpk2z.png

Unfortunately, after trying to edit it, this is the error I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDQus.png

After running @Clive's script, I couldn't flush the cache and I received these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: label in entity_views_field_definition() (line 191 of /home/accuairt/public_html/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/entity/views/entity.views.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: search_api_views_fulltext in views_handler_filter->accept_exposed_input() (line 1260 of /home/accuairt/public_html/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views/handlers/views_handler_filter.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: table in entity_views_plugin_row_entity_view->init() (line 20 of /home/accuairt/public_html/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/entity/views/plugins/entity_views_plugin_row_entity_view.inc).
SearchApiException: Unknown or invalid item type node. in search_api_get_datasource_controller() (line 1506 of /home/accuairt/public_html/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/search_api/search_api.module).
STATUS MESSAGE Operating in maintenance mode. Go online.
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

I restored a backup from a few hours ago to get the site back where it was.

edit: 12/18  Still looking for an answer.  There has to be a table I can clear to get rid of this information.

Answer (score 1):

If you know for definite that all products without a title should be deleted you can try something like this:

```
$query = new \EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'commerce_product')
  ->propertyCondition('title', '');

$results = $query->execute();
if (!empty($results['commerce_product'])) {
  commerce_product_delete_multiple(array_keys($results['commerce_product']));
}
```

It might be wise to inspect the results of the query before you run the delete function, just to make sure you're not deleting anything you want to keep by mistake.

Comment: I will run this in a minute.  Thank you!  I also have this additional information that may be helpful.  I have added to my original post to hopefully add some clarity to my issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not resolve the problem. I wasn't able to view my products, clear the cache, and even see the views of my products after running that.  I restored a backup from yesterday and it is all back to normal. Will post the errors I received in the main post.

Comment: Wow, no way that should've nuked the site. Have you got any custom/dev -version modules installed that could be causing issues? `SearchApiException: Unknown or invalid item type node` is especially strange

Comment: yeah I was surprised too!  The crawler has a handful of custom modules that it must be getting held up in.  I have no idea how Search API had an error either.  I am only one of two people working on this site, so maybe both of our actions at the time of enabling that code in a module caused the error.  I'll give it a shot one more time.